# JSON conversion in swift

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to convert some obj-c code to swift specifically part that handles JSON to swift conversion.

I have a JSON string

```
[{"ID":"1","Field1":"666666","Field2":"111111","Field3":"1","Field4":"30"},
 {"ID":"59","Field1":"SCJtDKw","Field2":"dwdSQz8v","Field3":"1","Field4":"1"}]
```

How can i convert this either into Array or dictionary?

I have tried

```
var ProductList : NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:&jsonerror) as NSDictionary
```

but this crashes on line:

```
0x1059ea662:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

I have also tried converting it as an array

```
var ProductList : NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:&jsonerror) as NSArray
```

This line gets further but then crashes on the following line (immediately after the above line)

```
 var ReturnValue : NSMutableArray = ProductList.objectAtIndex(0) as NSMutableArray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is an array of dictionaries (the outer square brackets is the array; the curly braces represent the dictionaries). So you want the `NSJSONSerialization` line to be cast as array. And when you grab the first item, that's a dictionary, so you should cast it as such (not an array).

```
let productList = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error:&jsonerror) as NSArray
let returnValue = productList.objectAtIndex(0) as NSDictionary
```

If you want, you could use Swift array of dictionaries, too:

```
if let productList = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error:&jsonerror) as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    let returnValue = productList[0]
    // use returnValue here
} else {
    println("JSONObjectWithData error: \(jsonerror)")
}
```

This second example also uses the `if let` optional binding to gracefully handle errors.